# Не работает менеджер программ

Tags: kde, linux-mint, linux

В Linux Mint 12 KDE не работает менеджер программ ( открывается на несколько секунд и тут же исчезает )

Comment: от супер пользователя пробовали?

Comment: а что за менеджер программ? ни разу под линуксом не возникала потребность в оном...

Answer (score 1):

запустить через терминал и посмотреть выхлоп